# How can I fix this VBA code to click a form button on Internet Explorer?

Tags: vba, automation, screen-scraping

I am writing a VBA code to open up a Internet Explorer, enter username and password and click a 'Sign On' Button.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub Example()

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True

    IE.navigate "webexample.com"

    Do While IE.busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do While IE.READYSTATE <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Do While IE.Document.READYSTATE <> "complete": DoEvents: Loop

    IE.Document.all.Item("userID").Value = "username"
    IE.Document.all.Item("password").Value = "password"
    IE.Document.forms(0).submit ("Sign On")

End Sub
```

And here is the HTML for the "Sign On" button:

```
<input name="action" class="button" type="SUBMIT" value="Sign On">
```

Is there something I'm missing or need to correct?  Any assistance is appreciated and I thank you in advance for your time and help!

Comment: sorry, here is the HTML for the "Sign On" button:

" <input name="action" class="button" type="SUBMIT" value="Sign On"> "

Comment: Can you list the URL?

Comment: What happens when you run your code ?

Comment: @justkrys - unfortunately not, it's an internal site with my company.

Comment: @TimWilliams - It will open the Internet Explorer, enter username and password, and then just stop.

Answer (score 0):

Providing more HTML would help as there may be parent frame/iframe to handle.

The element you show can, without parent frame/iframe, be selected with CSS selector combinations of `input.button[value='Sign On']`.

That is `input` tag element with class `button` and attribute `value` with value `'Sign On'`

```
ie.document.querySelector("input.button[value='Sign On']").Click
```